# Read numbers from a .txt file and store them in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, store

I've been trying to figure out how to read the scores and storing them in array.
been trying for sometime and its clearly not working out for me. Please help.

```
//ID    scores1 and 2
2000    62  40
3199    92  97
4012    75  65
6547    89  81
1017    95  95//.txtfile


int readresults (FILE* results , int* studID , int* score1 , int* score2);

{
// Local Declarations
int *studID[];
int *score1[];
int *score2[];

// Statements
check = fscanf(results , "%d%d%d",*studID[],score1[],score2[]);
if (check == EOF)
    return 0;
else if (check !=3)
    {
        printf("\aError reading data\n");
        return 0;
    } // if
else
    return 1;
```

Comment: will you always know how many scores you will read? if not then you will need to use a WHILE loop until you are done. Are you intending to call this function many times (once for each player) or just once?

Comment: yeah always student id and score 1 and score 2. and up to 50 scores anything beyond i will have to print a message such as “The file contains more than 50 students!” and terminate the program.

Comment: @KexyKathe: He means, whether the number of rows is set; in this case 5. Also, if you have the header in the file as you wrote it here, it needs to be taken care of too - read and discarded.

Comment: the .txt file only contains numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You declare variables twice, once in parameter list and once in "local declarations".
- The function brace is not closed.
- One `fscanf` can only read a number of items specified by its format string, in this case 3 (`"%d%d%d"`). It reads numbers, not arrays. To fill an array, you need a loop (`while`, or `for`).

**EDIT**

Okay, here's one way to do it:

```
#define MAX 50
#include <stdio.h>

int readresults(FILE *results, int *studID, int *score1, int *score2) {
  int i, items;
  for (i = 0;
      i < MAX && (items = fscanf(results, "%d%d%d", studID + i, score1 + i, score2 + i)) != EOF;
      i++) {
    if (items != 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error reading data\n");
      return -1; // convention: non-0 is error
    }
  }
  return 0; // convention: 0 is okay
}

int main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("a.txt", "r");
  int studID[MAX];
  int score1[MAX];
  int score2[MAX];
  readresults(f, studID, score1, score2);
}
```

Comment: #define MAX=50;

for (i<max && fscanf(fpIn,"%d %d %d",&studID &score1, &score2)!=EOF)

Comment: No, that's not `for` syntax; but it's closer. If you use `while` instead of `for` there, that's a big step in the right direction. Now you have to fill the loop body with putting those three values in correct places in the array. (You could also directly read into array elements, but that's an advanced exercise, I suppose.)

Comment: i still dont understand.isit this?
    while(i<MAX && fscanf (fpIn,"%*d,%d,%d",&score1, &score2)!=EOF);
    score[i++] = score1;
    score[j++] = score2;

Comment: @KexyKathe: There, solved it for you. Ask in detail about things you don't understand.

Comment: "stderr" sorry what is this

Comment: @KexyKathe: UNIX has two main places to output things, like two voices. The regular one ("standard output", predefined globally as `FILE *stdout`) is the place where `printf` normally writes (`printf(...)` is equivalent to `fprintf(stdout, ...)`. The shouty one is `stderr`, which is where error messages are supposed to go. You can replace it with the regular `printf("Error")` if you're not comfortable with it - it makes no real difference for your task.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call that function just once and have it read the scores for all of the students, you should use something like this:

```
int i=0;
check = fscanf(results , "%d %d %d",&id[i],&score1[i],&score2[i]);
while(check!=EOF){
        i++;
        check = fscanf(results , "%d %d %d",&id[i],&score1[i],&score2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: ok, then you just need to use the index of the array in each while iteration.Just  Edited the answer

Comment: I need to discard the ID so i add a %*d right? and my function header should be 
int readresults (FILE* AG_midterm ,int* score1[] , int* score2[])?

Comment: dont forget the student id

Comment: but i need to discard it as i need only the scores to avg them and print them in descending order.

Comment: oh, yea, you dont need it in that case